# Interface for Elasticsearch facet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, elasticsearch, facet, blacklight

I am using elasticsearch in a Ruby on Rails project. I am in search of user interface for elasticsearch index.

Like [Blacklight](http://projectblacklight.org/) is for solr, is there any alternative of blacklight for elasticsearch ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try sense - a JSON aware interface to ElasticSearch

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/

Comment: Thanks for reply. JSON interface is nice but i need something like [this](http://demo.projectblacklight.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice plugin for SOLR and Elasticsearch facets

https://github.com/okfn/facetview

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some of the great [elasticsearch plugins](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html). I personally use the [head plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) to have an overview over my cluster, indices, etc.. and also check the data indexed. [Bigdesk](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk) is nice have some general real time monitoring of your cluster. Already mentioned by Siddardha Budige was sense which is great for experimenting and debugging queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i tried these plugins. These are elasticsearch management tools. I was looking for a facet interface like blacklight is for SOLR that i mentioned the question.

Comment: Maybe in this case you should try out Kibana: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/. Still not 100% sure it fits your needs, since I never used or have seen blacklight. Kibana can be used to create dashboards of any kind on top of your indices, including some using elasticsearch facets.

Comment: Torsten: I found a JS alternative for elasticsearch facets. Thanks for your response

Comment: please Torsten, can you share wich alternative have you found?

Comment: @Qsebas you have to ask Arif, since he wrote that comment.

Comment: sorry Tortsen I was confused with the thread... so @Arif can you tell us what have you found?

Answer (score 0):

Found nice project, pure HTML and Javascript (can work on any server-side framework)
[ElasticUI](http://www.elasticui.com/)